# async move protocol violation and/or connection lost ONVIF

Tags: c#, asynchronous, onvif

**Some background infos:**

I'm currently making a c# windows form app using visual studio 2017 and using the ONVIF .wsdl (OnvifMedia10 and OnvifPTZService).

I have admin access to the target camera.

I got a profile from the mediaClient I created:

```
var mediaEndPointAddress = new EndpointAddress($"http://{cameraAddress}/onvif/media");
var mediaEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
     MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None)
};
var mediaBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
     AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest
};
var mediaCustomBinding = new CustomBinding(mediaEncoding, mediaBinding);
var mediaPasswordDigestBehavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(userName, password);
mediaClient = new MediaClient(mediaCustomBinding, mediaEndPointAddress);
mediaClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(mediaPasswordDigestBehavior);

var profs = mediaClient.GetProfiles();

profile = mediaClient.GetProfile(profs[0].token);
```

The `PasswordDigestBehavior` is part of some code I found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272227/onvif-wsdl-service-unable-to-authenticate).

I used the same methodology to get a ptzClient and it's configurations:

```
...
var ptzEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress($"http://{cameraAddress}/onvif/ptz");
ptzClient = new PTZClient(commonCustomBinding, ptzEndpointAddress);
ptzClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(commonPasswordDigestBehavior);
var configs = ptzClient.GetConfigurations();
options = ptzClient.GetConfigurationOptions(configs[0].token);
```

I then created a `PTZSpeed` variable to keep the way I want my camera to move:

```
velocity = new OnvifPTZService.PTZSpeed();
velocity.PanTilt = new OnvifPTZService.Vector2D();
velocity.Zoom = new OnvifPTZService.Vector1D();
```

**My question:**

When I want to rotate the target camera, I use some kind of `PanLeft()` function:

```
public void PanLeft()
    {
        if(Initialised && CanPanTilt)
        {
            velocity.PanTilt.x = options.Spaces.ContinuousPanTiltVelocitySpace[0].XRange.Min;
            velocity.PanTilt.y = 0;
            ptzClient.ContinuousMoveAsync(profile.token, velocity, "PT5S");
        }
    }
```

And to stop the camera, I change back the `velocity.PanTilt.x` and the `velocity.PanTilt.y` to zero, before sending another async move request.

**After a couple of move/stop, I keep loosing connection to my camera...**

I wonder if it's because I make too many async requests in the same time or something...

At first, I thought the problem was with my network since I was connecting to the camera through wifi, but I tried connecting it directly with an ethernet cable and it didn't change a thing...

I want to know if my way to do the movement is ok, if there's a better way to do it without having my app breaking and receiving the errors in my title (protocol violation and such)...

I also use the [OnvifDeviceManager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/) app to guide myself through the development of this project, to see what I can and cannot do, but it seems that even this app is crashing/loosing connection to the camera after a couple of ptz actions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that there's too many move request sent/received at the same time...

But, I just found out that there's a `ptzClient.Stop(profile.token, true, false)` function that does exactly what I want...

It stops the given ptzClient from panning/tilting if the first bool is true and it stops the zooming if the second bool is true.

My application seems to last longer when I use this command.

The problem is still there, but it's less frequent!